# Bootstrap navbar does not show in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navbar

I have imported bootstrap in ruby on rails
And I have copied the `navbar` code in the bootstrap website.
Yet, the bootstrap toolbar does not show in the ruby on rails page 
with  `<% render 'layouts/navigation' %>`
I a quite new in stackoverflow and with ruby on rails and not a professional web developer. So please forgive me if my question is not adequately expressed.

Comment: Does that file exist? Have you added it? Bootstrap gem won't generate a navigation for you. It simply adds the js and css files to the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

Change the line

```
<% render 'layouts/navigation' %>
```

to:

```
 <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
```